# Facebook connect is very slow, can I use AJAX?

Tags: php, facebook, fbconnect

I'm implementing the facebook php sdk and using it for user login/connect.
Everything works as expected, however, at the top of each page, I need to call
$facebook->api('/me') to determine if the user is logged in or not..

This call is very slow, sometimes, taking up to 2 seconds to return.

So, any interaction by the user, always has a 1-2 sec delay before any page loads..

I suspect, it's because, the $facebook->api('/me') call is using httpS ..

Any suggestions....

```
          $facebook = new Facebook(array( 'appId'  => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',  'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',));
          $user = $facebook->getUser();
          if ($user)
           {
           try                               {  $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET'); }
           catch (FacebookApiException $e)   {  error_log($e);  $user = null;  }
           }
          $login_parms = array('scope' => 'user_birthday', 'redirect_uri' => 'http://xxx.com/login');
          $login_link  = $facebook->getLoginUrl($login_parms);


          if($user) 
           {
           /* logged in */
           }
          else
           {
           /* not */
           }
```

Comment: My question re: ajax was.. could i call $facebook->api('me') in the background ??

Comment: The answer to your question is: yes, you can :)

Comment: If that is the only section of the page that depends on the answer then yes just use ajax, if anything else on that page eg content or menus depend on that answer then you will have to wait for the answer before rendering some of the remaining page content anyway

Answer (score 2):

You really shouldn't perform the Facebook API request on each page load. Only do it once when the user logs in. Then you can store the "logged in" flag in the session (or a signed cookie).

If you need to store e.g. some of the user's facebook profile information, also put it in the session or your database.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need to get "fresh" values from $facebook->api("/me").
Then I would suggest you cache the response, if you use any PHP-framework (eg. Zend, Yii, Codeigniter) this should be really straight forward.

If you're not using a PHP-framework i suggest you still look into the excellent ZF documentation for their cache solution.

[Zend Framework - Cache](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.cache.html)

If you, however, need fresh values each load you can make a simple page that only returns the $facebook->api("/me") part and returns it as bare HTML. Then simply keep a  or similar that recieves the response when it's finished. 
An easy solution would be using jQuery and just write:

```
$("#div-id").load("/page-that-returns-facebook-api-me-result");
```

Answer (score 0):

Add some spinning wheel where login form is, then call ajax on document ready to your php script, script returns false or loged in user data (or more data if you need - redirect url) and then depending on result show form to login or display currently loged in user.

What i mean Javascript will handle all logic depending on what is returned from server, redirects, change UI etc.

Another way is to cache (session with expiration) first call to facebook  if user is loged in remember it. And check if that Session variable is present and not yet expired. Only call again when doing some sensitive tasks or get expired.

Comment: I would not suggest using javascript for authentication purposes (eg. redirecting an unauthorized user).

- But perhaps I misunderstood your sentence "What i mean Javascript will handle all logic depending on what is returned from server, redirects, change UI etc."

Comment: All authentication logic still must be on server, and yes i prefer not using javascript, but i do not see security issue when everything is handled from server. What i mean "logic" is UI.